# MySQL TEXT or VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, text, storage, varchar

We have a very large historical table that contains a column with at most 500 UTF8 characters, and the disk space grows really fast!

We're having at least 2 million rows a day... and we were wondering which would do a better job (mostly in storage but in performance as well)? TEXT or VARCHAR(512)?

Comment: http://www.pythian.com/news/7129/text-vs-varchar/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VARCHAR is probably preferable in your case from both the storage and performance perspective.  View this [oft-reposted article](http://www.pythian.com/news/7129/text-vs-varchar/).

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964) is useful information; I think in general, the answer is the varchar is usually the better bet.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL manual:

> In most respects, you can regard a
>   BLOB column as a VARBINARY column that
>   can be as large as you like.
>   Similarly, you can regard a TEXT
>   column as a VARCHAR column. BLOB and
>   TEXT differ from VARBINARY and VARCHAR
>   in the following ways:
>
> ```
> There is no trailing-space removal for BLOB and TEXT columns when values
> ```
>
> are stored or retrieved. Before MySQL
>   5.0.3, this differs from VARBINARY and VARCHAR, for which trailing spaces are
>   removed when values are stored.
>
> ```
> On comparisons, TEXT is space extended to fit the compared object,
> ```
>
> exactly like CHAR and VARCHAR.
>
> ```
> For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index
> ```
>
> prefix length. For CHAR and VARCHAR, a
>   prefix length is optional. See Section
>   7.5.1, “Column Indexes”.
>
> ```
> BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.
> ```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html