# Short messages / notices MySQL type

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I would like to make a simple notice / news system for website administrators.

What is the best solution, to store those messages (up to 250 characters) in database?

VARCHAR(255) or TEXT?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL TEXT or VARCHAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128626/mysql-text-or-varchar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are to be short, define a hard upper limit and use VARCHAR(). If you don't think they'll go above 250 chars, make the size `VARCHAR(512)` to give yourself plenty of room to change your mind at a moment's notice. (You could always alter the column definition later anyway).

`TEXT` and `BLOB` types are really intended for data of unknown/undetermined/unlimited length. If you have no problem defining a limit, then define one and use `VARCHAR()`. You'll get more flexibility out of sorting and indexing from `VARCHAR()`, as `TEXT` can only use up to `max_sort_length` bytes to sort on.

If it matters for your use case, you cannot assign a default value to `TEXT` columns.

Much of this is detailed in the [MySQL documentation on `BLOB` & `TEXT` types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the text/message will never exceed 250 characters, using `VARCHAR2(255)` is more advisable. But if in later dates/times, you might increase it, you can do that later. :)