# varchar or text for string a length just 360 characters

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I am using mysql to store values of graph database and comes to around atmost 360 chars , is it advisible to use varchar instead of text? since I will be frequentyy quering, also the table will keep increasing in rows over time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL TEXT or VARCHAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128626/mysql-text-or-varchar)

Answer (score 1):

for so few charachters you should use `varchar`. `Varchar` could store up to 65535 charachters. There is no need for you to use `text`